# Change TikZ's default coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the TikZ manual I read that the default coordinate system's spacing is 1cm, so that (1,1) would be a vector going 1cm in x-direction and 1cm in y. In a diagram with a lot of nodes, that I am placing using the options such as `above =of ...`, this spacing is too much.

In order to change that, how can I change the coordinate system's default spacing?

Comment: I have deleted my answer since I totally misread your question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Not a problem. Can you explain why you misunderstood my question? That could help me formulating better questions in the future.

Comment: Actually it is a mistake on my side. I think you have formulated your question in a good way. It is the last sentence that made me think that you are looking for a change in the unit length of the axis which is the first part of Torbjorn's answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the coordinate system with `x=<length>` and `y=<length>` as options to a `tikzpicture`, e.g.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
```

however in your case you would probably rather change the `node distance`, as this defines the distance between nodes when using the `above=of` syntax:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm]
```

or

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0.5cm and 0.5cm]
```

The difference between these two cases is illustrated in the TikZ/PGF manual (§16.5.3 Advanced Placement Options, pages 187-188, for v. 2.10).

You could also set this globally, by using `\tikzset`, i.e. add

```
\tikzset{node distance=0.5cm and 0.5cm}
```

to your preamble.